# AWS Cloudformation - Security group template error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Quick question: Unable to create an EC2 instance attached with a Security Group.

Thanks in advance.

> Error: Encountered unsupported property SecurityGroupInrgress

Template:

```yaml
Resources: 
    MyInstance: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::Instance 
        Properties: 
            AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a 
            ImageId: ami-a4c7edb2
            InstanceType: t2.micro 
            SecurityGroups: 
                - !Ref SSHSecurityGroup 
                - !Ref ServerSecurityGroup 
    MyEIP: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::EIP 
        Properties: 
            InstanceId: !Ref MyInstance 
    SSHSecurityGroup: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties: 
            GroupDescription: Enable inbound SSH access via port 22 
            SecurityGroupInrgress: 
                - FromPort: 22
                  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
                  IpProtocol: tcp 
    ServerSecurityGroup: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties: 
            GroupDescription: Allow connections from mentioned IPs and ports
            SecurityGroupIngress: 
                - FromPort: 80
                  IpProtocol: tcp 
                  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I wonder what I am missing out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mispelt in the `SSHSecurityGroup` resource, you typed `SecurityGroupInrgress` but it should be `SecurityGroupIngress`.

Comment: I wonder why AWS template designer was validating this config without any errors. Anyways, thanks alot.

Comment: Haha, no problem. We all do it. Have a great day :)